# Find the number of $5$ digit combinations from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ in which some digit occurs at least three times.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There exists this thread:

[find the number of five digit combinations from the set ${1,2,3,4,5}$ where some digits occur at least three times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149020/find-the-number-of-five-digit-combinations-from-the-set-1-2-3-4-5-where-some)

In the linked thread they obtained a different answer. Likely because we are counting different objects. Multisets in my case and strings in the linked thread.

The answer given in my book is $5\binom52_R = 75$ where R stands for repetition. In other words, $\binom52_R$ counts multisets.

I have three questions:

(a) Are the answers different in my book and the linked thread because different objects are counted(multisets vs strings with repetition)?

(b) If we are counting multisets, then we are counting objects of the form $\{x, x, x, y, z\}$ where $y, z$ are not necessarily different. We biject a multiset to a list like so: $\{x, x, x, y, z\} \leftrightarrow (x, \{y, z\})$ where $y, z$ don't have to be distinct. Then the number of these lists is $5\binom52_R = 75$. Does that make sense? I was wondering how they obtained the answer in my book.

(c) Is it possible to solve this problem breaking it into cases like

Let $A = {\text{all multisets in which some digit occurs three times}} \\ B = {\text{all multisets in which some digit occurs four times}} \\ C = {\text{all multisets in which some digit occurs five times}}$

One way I tried solving this problem by breaking into cases is below. What went wrong there?

We count elements in $|A|, |B|, |C|$  by bijecting multisets to lists: $\{x, x, x, y, z\} \leftrightarrow (x, \{y, z\})$ where $y, z$ are different from each other.

Then

$|A| = 5\binom 52, \\ |B| = 5\binom 51, \\ |C| = 5$

$|A \cap B| = 5\binom 52, \\ |A \cap C| = 5\binom 52, \\ |B \cap C| = \binom 51, \\ |A \cap B \cap C| = 5\binom 52.$

Thus,

$|A \cup B \cup C| = (50 + 25 + 5) - (50 + 50 + 5) + 50  = 25.$

Comment: "The answer given in my book is" why does your book have an answer to something johnson wrote on these boards this February?  *How* does your book have an answer to this question? Books take months to publish so how did the publishers know what johnson was going to post here?  Obviously your book has an answer to something *like* what johnson posted but these are not the exact same question.  What is the exact question that you book has?

Comment: Question: http://imgur.com/a/gBeHh, Answer: http://imgur.com/a/lKDuC As for your other questions, I have no idea.

Comment: Here's my book: https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorics-Oriented-Mathematical-Association-Textbooks/dp/0883857103/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1497113488&sr=8-1&keywords=combinatorics+problem+oriented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count of $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$ is strange.

I'd order the admissible combinations according to *type*, i.e. the induced partition of $5$, the common cardinality of the multisets in question. Since this partition has to contain a part of size $\geq3$ containing a part of size $\geq3$ there  are four such types, namely 
$$(5),\quad (4,1),\quad (3,2),\quad (3,1,1)\ .$$
E.g., the type $(4,1)$ characterizes multisets containing $4$ copies of a certain $x$ and $1$ copy of a certain $y\ne x$. Similarly, the type $(3,1,1)$ characterizes multisets containing $3$ copies of a certain $x$ and one copy of each of two elements $y\ne z$, both $\ne x$.

The first type can be realized in $5$ ways. The second and the third in $5\cdot4$ ways, and the third in $5\cdot{4\choose2}$ ways, giving a total of $75$.

Comment: Just to clarify, $(3, 2)$ corresponds to the set $\{x, x, x, y, y\}$ while $(3, 1, 1) \leftrightarrow \{x, x, x, y, z\}$, correct? If so, how are you counting the types? Does the type (3, 1, 1) correspond to the list $(x, \{y, z\})$?